# Injecting JwtBearerOptions into a controller

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

In `Startup.cs` I enable JWT auth, which works perfectly across my app.

```
b.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = key,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = JwtConstants.Issuer,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = JwtConstants.Audience,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});
```

In one of my controllers, I would like to get a handle on the `TokenValidationParameters` that are set in the `Startup.cs` config. I thought I would be able to do this by providing my controller constructor with `IOptions<JwtBearerOptions> options` and reading `options.Value.TokenValidationParameters`, however, when injected the properties do not match the values set in `Startup.cs`.

My ultimate goal is to manually validate a JWT token, like below.

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var user = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the options you registered with your authentication scheme during startup, you'll have to use the `IOptionsMonitor` to extract the named options.

In your controller, inject it like this

```
public YourController(IOptionsMonitor<JwtBearerOptions> jwtOptions, ...) { ... }
```

Then when you want to get the instance of the options, you get it with the same name as you used to register the authentication scheme. Like this in your case:

```
var yourOptions = _jwtOptions.Get(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

You can read more about the options pattern in aspnet core here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thank you so much @Fredrik. Finding this answer today made my day